# How to create a count-up timer in VBA

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I am trying to create a counter that increments 1 every second in VBA of Powerpoint presentation. This is what I have come up so far.

```
Sub countup()
    Dim index As Integer

    index = 0
    Do Until index > 100
    index = index + 1

    DoEvents
        With ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes(3).TextFrame.TextRange
        .Text = index
        End With

    Loop
End Sub
```

This code increments 1 until 101 but it does not increment 1 every second. This is in VBA Powerpoint so I cannot put a timer control. Hope you could help. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a possible solution:

```
Public Declare Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32" (ByVal dwMilliseconds As Long)

Public Sub TestMe2()

    Dim index As Long
    index = 0

    Do Until index > 10
        index = index + 1
        Debug.Print index
        Sleep (1000)
    Loop

End Sub
```

Without adding `.Net` features, its possible to do it like this:

```
Public Sub TestMe()

    Dim lngIndex            As Long
    Dim sngSec              As Single '9GAG
    Dim sngAddSec           As Single

    sngAddSec = 1

    Do Until lngIndex > 4
        lngIndex = lngIndex + 1
        sngSec = Timer + sngAddSec
        Debug.Print lngIndex
        While Timer < sngSec: Wend
    Loop

End Sub
```